# Как создать форму регистрации почты на PHP? (Почтовый сервер)

Tags: php, веб-программирование, email, exim

Как сделать регистрацию почты на PHP (Exim)
Здраствуйте, я хочу сделать автоматическую регистрацию почты и не знаю как именно это сделать - уже долго гуглил и пробовал много варианатов.
Как именно мне сделать регистрацию почты с помощью PHP?

Comment: Ну, изучить html и сверстать желаемую страничку с желаемой формой? Или в чём суть вопроса?

Comment: В том что нужно как то отправлять запрос почтовому серверу на счёт регистрации почты, никаких API нету нормальных, а почтовый сервер ещё и на линуксе(Exim), как посылать неизвестно.

Comment: Ну тогда это вопрос не про форму и вообще не про php, а про администрирование почтового сервера exim, а вы его в тексте вопроса даже не упомянули